# Is it possible to get XML elements based on some attribute value/s using JAXB?

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, jaxb

I have created an XML file using JAXB named `Height.xml`. The structure looks like the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<heightList>
    <measurement id="5">
        <height>4'4"</height>
    </measurement>
    <measurement id="4">
        <height>4'3"</height>
    </measurement>
    <measurement id="3">
        <height>4'2"</height>
    </measurement>
    <measurement id="2">
        <height>4'1"</height>
    </measurement>
    <measurement id="1">
        <height>4'0"</height>
    </measurement>
</heightList>
```

This XML file can be unmarshalled to a `List<Height>` as follows.

```
JAXBContext jaxb=JAXBContext.newInstance(HeightList.class);
File file=new File("Height.xml");
List<Height> heightList = ((HeightList) jaxb.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(file)).getList();
```

Is it possible to get an XML element based on its attribute `id` so that instead of `List<Height>`, only one object of type `Height` is fetched? The `id` attribute is unique.

---

The associated classes:

Height:

```
public final class Height implements Serializable
{
    private Integer id;
    private String height;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Height() {}

    @XmlAttribute(name = "id")
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public void setHeight(String height) {
        this.height = height;
    }
}
```

HeightList:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "heightList")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
public final class HeightList implements Serializable
{
    @XmlElement(name="measurement")
    private List<Height>list;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public HeightList() {}

    public HeightList(List<Height> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    public List<Height> getList() {
        return list;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a List heightList, which you retrieve from the document/object tree without any additional overhead - it is part of that tree. Partial unmarshalling isn't done.

To locate the Height with a specific ID value:

```
Height getById( List<Height> list, Integer id ){
    for( Height h: list ){
        if( h.getId().equals(id) ) return h;
    }
    return null;
}
```

It might be worth considering something like XSLT to reduce the XML document to one containing a single `<mesurement>`  and unmarshal that.

Probably not worth the effort unless the list is very long.